# Help finding probability generating function

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have an exercise where X has an exponential distribution with rate 1, and Y|X=x is a poisson distribution with parameter x.

I can find the expectation and variance of Y using the law of total expectation and law of total variance - and I have gotten 1 and 2 respectively - I'm fairly sure this is correct.

Now I am trying to find the probability generating function of Y, but I'm struggling. I think I need to use the law of total expectation to help me here, but I'm not too sure how.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $\displaystyle P(Y=n) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty P(Y=n \mid X = x)f_X(x)\,\mathrm dx$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $G(z)$ is the desired PGF we have,

$$G(z) = E[z^Y] = E[E[z^Y|X]]$$

We also have that
$$E[z^Y|X=x] = \exp({-x(1-z)})$$

since this is just the PGF of a Poisson random variable with parameter $x$. Then we have that

$$G(z) = E[\exp(-X(1-z))] = \int_0^\infty e^{-x(1-z)}e^{-x}dx = \frac{1}{2-z}.$$

---

EDIT: Proof that PGF of Poisson random variable with parameter $\lambda$ is $\exp(-\lambda(1-z)$.

Let $X$ be Poisson with parameter $\lambda$. By the definition of Poisson random variables, we have

$$P(X=x) = \frac{\lambda^n}{n!} e^{-\lambda}$$
so $$\begin{align}E[z^X] &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda}\\
&= e^{-\lambda}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(z\lambda)^n}{n!}\\
&= e^{-\lambda}e^{\lambda z}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure how you evaluated E[z^Y|X=x] = \exp({-x(1-z)})

Comment: @Q1O3 see my edit.

Comment: Thanks, it makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

Compute the unconditional distribution of $Y$:  $$\Pr[Y = y] = \int_{x=0}^\infty \Pr[Y = y \mid X = x]f_X(x) \, dx.$$  Then compute the PGF ${\rm E}[z^Y]$.